# How can I jump back after `rope-goto-definition`?

Tags: python, motion

I am using `rope-goto-definition` to jump into a module's definition, [link](https://github.com/python-rope/ropemacs#shortcuts). But I cannot jump back to where I was. `xref-pop-marker-stack` says `Marker stack is empty`. Is it possible to jump back after running `rope-goto-definition`? Similiar behavior is done using `jedi:goto-definition-pop-marker`.

---

My setup:

```
(require 'pymacs)
(pymacs-load "ropemacs" "rope-")
(setq ropemacs-enable-autoimport 't)
(setq ropemacs-autoimport-modules '("os" "shutil"))

(defun goto-def-or-jedi ()
  "Go to definition of thing at point or do an rgrep in project if that fails"
  (interactive)
  (condition-case nil (rope-goto-definition)
    (error (rope-goto-definition (thing-at-point 'symbol)))))
```

---

Note: On there github its said that: `ropemacs is completely unmaintained and abandoned.` [link](https://github.com/python-rope/ropemacs/issues/41#issuecomment-789719535). So there is no hope to have support from developers. Maybe before jump, the location can be pushed into the stack?

Comment: Is it any particular reason to use rope? With lsp + python, ```xref-pop-marker-stack``` works flawlessly.

Comment: just rope has auto-import option but actually no. I just want to jump into definition and get back. I wasn't able to setup of lsp + python for that that's why I also end up in rope. How can I use lsp +python to jump into module definitions?

Comment: I do not know what you tried with lsp, here are two steps to check the combination 
lsp+python: First install python-language-server as described [https://github.com/palantir/python-language-server/blob/develop/README.rst]("here"),
including all 3rd party plugins. (install [all]).

Comment: Clone [https://github.com/rksm/emacs-rust-config] this package to check/play with lsp , it does not interfere with your emacs configuration - while this is written for rust, before installing it, just edit the file ```init.el``` and comment out the lines 9..35 and 48 and add the following ```(use-package python :ensure nil),``` save and install packages. Then open a python file, and ```M-x lsp``` to start lsp, ```M-x lsp-find-definiton``` of a function and ```M-x xref-pop-marker-stack``` to return to source file. Or use the already binded keys ```s-l g g``` and ```M-,```.

Comment: Should I add `(use-package python :ensure nil),` to line 9 ? including `,`? How can I install it afterwards? like `(load "standalone.el")`?

Comment: M-x lsp says `LSP :: The following servers support current file but do not have automatic installation configuration: jedi
You may find the installation instructions at https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/languages.
(If you have already installed the server check *lsp-log*). ` :-(

Comment: No, do not add ```,```, was typing mistake. The purpose is to add python package instead of rust (no need for that).

Comment: I have done following which also installed the packages `emacs -q -nw --load /home/alper/.emacs.d/emacs-rust-config/standalone.el Driver.py`. Than `M-x lsp ` and `M-x lsp-find-definition` which says: `The connected server(s) does not support method textDocument/implementation.
To find out what capabilities support your server use ‘M-x lsp-describe-session’
and expand the capabilities section` not sure what's wrong

Comment: Clone ```emacs-rust-config``` in a separate folder in your home directory, not in ```.emacs.d```. Do not mix configurations, this should be a separate one. And you need to have jedi module installed in your python.

Comment: Done seems like it is connected to lsp and give some information while I move around like function definitons and so on but not sure how I can combine this my own init.el and theme. And still lsp-goto-definition still says `The connected server(s) does not support method textDocument/implementation.`  but `xref-find-definitions` works flawlessly like you say

Comment: “So there is no hope to have support from developers” Current (unwilling) ropemacs maintainer speaking: pull requests will be certainly considered, and taking over the project would be welcome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put a mark at `rope-goto-definition` with https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/auto-mark.el

```
(require 'auto-mark)
  (setq auto-mark-command-class-alist
        '((anything . anything)
          (rope-goto-definition . jump)
          (indent-for-tab-command . ignore)
          (undo . ignore)))
  (setq auto-mark-command-classifiers
        (list (lambda (command)
                (if (and (eq command 'self-insert-command)
                         (eq last-command-event ? ))
                    'ignore))))
  (global-auto-mark-mode 1)
```

Then you can use `pop-global-mark` or `pop-local-mark` depending on whether there is a change of buffer or not.
unfortunately with this solution it is up to the user to manage when to use local or global marks.

Comment: Please, make it into pull request against https://github.com/python-rope/ropemacs

Comment: @mcepl This "solution" is a workaround... I don't think it's a good idea to integrate this code. If we want this evolution in ropemacs, we will have to take the time to do it properly.